# Trying to include data from a specific row as input to a "parent" query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to pull data from two tables where I need every column from the first table and the last row for a specific id in the second table. I have the following query

```
SELECT RequestTable.*,
   ProcessTable.processType,
   ProcessTable.employeeId,
   ProcessTable.processId
FROM RequestTable,
   ProcessTable
WHERE RequestTable.requestId = ProcessTable.requestId
ORDER BY ProcessTable.processId DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Right now this is only returning one entry because of the LIMIT 1. How can I change this query so that it says something along the lines of:

```
SELECT RequestTable.*,
   ProcessTable.processType,
   ProcessTable.employeeId,
   ProcessTable.processId
FROM RequestTable,
   ProcessTable
WHERE RequestTable.requestId = ProcessTable.requestId
   AND * * * * ProcessTable.processType IS
FROM THE LAST ROW
FROM ProcessTable
WHERE ProcessTable.requestId = RequestTable.requestId
```

I'm basically logging changes to a status and I need to pull the last inserted status for a given id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Can you show the schema of the tables and the expected result? Because i'm not understanding how do you want this formatted in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The two tables you're talking about are `RequestTable` and `ProcessTable`, respectively?  You want each request and the most recent process step for each?

First you need to write a query against `ProcessTable` which will pull one record per `requestId`.  Without knowing your schema, I can only guess that it would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    RequestID, ProcessType, EmployeeID, ProcessID
FROM
    ProcessTable AS PT
WHERE
    -- Exclude this record if there is another with the same RequestID but a later ProcessID
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProcessTable AS PT2 WHERE PT.RequestID = PT2.RequestID AND PT2.ProcessID > PT.ProcessID)
```

This assumes that `ProcessID` is an incrementing integer, such that the most recent record will always have the highest `ProcessID`.

Once that's done, we can easily join it to the first table, as a subquery:

```
SELECT
    RT.*,
    PT.ProcessType,
    PT.EmployeeID,
    PT.ProcessID
FROM
    RequestTable AS RT
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            RequestID, ProcessType, EmployeeID, ProcessID
        FROM
            ProcessTable AS PT
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProcessTable AS PT2 WHERE PT.RequestID = PT2.RequestID AND PT2.ProcessID > PT.ProcessID)
        ) AS PT ON RT.RequestID = PT.RequestID
ORDER BY
    PT.ProcessID
```

One note: don't join your tables in the `WHERE` clause, it's asking for trouble (ever accidentally cross join two million-row records?  Ouch).  Put your join logic in the `FROM` clause, that's where it belongs.